# geom_polygon color settings are ignored

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]
This is a public map of Munich, where my color settings are being ignored.

```
sf[, "mycol"] <- c("white")
sf[sf$id>=1080, "mycol"] <- c("blue")

map <- ggplot(data = sf, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id)) + 
  geom_path() + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = mycol, group = id)) + 
  clean_theme()
print(map)
```

How to address the data errors / holes?

Comment: Since you've defined your color values explicitly, try adding `scale_fill_identity()` to your code?

Comment: thank you - we are nearly there: colors are correct now while the "holes" remain.

Comment: Without having sight of your data `sf`, it's hard to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: thank you - I decided to cheat and add `panel.background = element_rect(fill="white")` to my theme